# How to trigger same microsoft flow for different document libraries

Tags: sharepoint-online, microsoft-flow

I have several Document libraries in which whenever a file is uploaded into a document library flow should be triggered.So is it possible to trigger the document library on a single flow instead of a separate flow for each document library.

Comment: you will have to deploy flow for each library.